# Окна на сайте в виде диалогов ВК

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать всплывающие окна на сайте в виде терминала которые можно передвигать и масштабировать. Что-то вроде диалогов ВК. Подскажите, пожалуйста, ключевые слова, ссылки, фреймворки...